# use webp pictures for products

Tags: magento2, product-images, products

I use a magento2 webshop https://www.agoshop.at and I will use webp pictures for my products.
I have convert a jpg to webp format and try to upload this webp picture to a product but the filetyp will not be accepted.
Hope someone can help me there how I can use webp pictures for my products.
kindly regards for any answer

Answer (score 0):

I almost feel it is spammy, but just to mention: A free way of implementing WebP is here:

https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/webp2

https://marketplace.magento.com/magecomp-magento-2-webp-image-support.html